# Tensorflow does not allow for multiple object returned in the call function

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the call method in my class that extends tf.keras.Model:

```
def call(self, inputs):
    """
    Forward pass through the model. Used during training.
    """
    model_out = self.base_model(inputs)
    return model_out, inputs
```

As you can see, I am returning the outputs as well as the inputs.

Therefore, in my custom loss, the call method looks like this:

```
def __call__(self, returns, model_output):
    weights, positions = model_output
    ....
    return -loss_value
```

When I test in isolation, everything works, but when I create the model and try to fit it, I get:

```
weights, positions = model_output

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Comment: The idea is that I always need the inputs to make additional calculations for my loss. 

Currently, I have passed the inputs as class attribute in the loss class, but this is a "dirty" fix, things will break if there is shuffling and so on. 

Moreover, if I add validation_data to my model.fit, the loss will mess up again because of indexing the original feautres.

Everything will work if tensorflow didnt complain about my approach.

Comment: Rewrote the whole thing in PyTorch, it seems that tensorflow just sucks.